# Solve this integral equation using Laplace transform

Tags: laplace-transform, integral-equations

> Solve this integral equation using Laplace transform
>
> $$f(x)=x^2 + \int_{0}^{x}f^{\prime}(x-t) e^{-at} dt ,f(0)=0 $$

Please Help

see mu answer below

Thank you for your participation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Solution:-

Applying Laplace transform , we get

$$\bar f(s)=\frac{2!}{s^3}+L[f^{\prime}(x);s].L[e^{-at};s]$$
$$\bar f(s)=\frac{2}{s^3}+[s\bar f(s)-f(0)].[\frac{1}{s+a}]$$
$$\bar f(s)=\frac{2}{s^3}+\frac{s\bar f(s)}{s+a}$$
$$(1-\frac{s}{s+a})\bar f(s)=\frac{2}{s^3}$$
$$(\frac{a}{s+a})\bar f(s)=\frac{2}{s^3}$$
$$\bar f(s)=\frac{2(s+a)}{as^3}$$
$$\bar f(s)=\frac{2}{a}[\frac{1}{s^2}+\frac{a}{s^3}]$$
Applying the inverse transform , we get

$$f(x)=\frac{2}{a}[x+\frac{a}{2}x^2]$$
$$f(x)=\frac{2}{a}x+x^2$$

> Is this true solution?
>
> Is there a simplification of the final answer